# Can the 'Other Contacts' group be hidden in Lync?

Tags: lync

Is there a way to hide the 'Other Contacts' Group that appears by default in Lync?

I can "Rename" or "Delete" any Group that I've made on my own, but 'Other Contacts' doesn't offer those commands when I right-click it.

The 'View More Layout Options' menu did let me hide the 'Frequent Contacts' group, but there's no mention of 'Other Contacts' in there.

It isn't mentioned anywhere in the Options dialog, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried but with no success to remove this group, and since the "Other Contacts" an original group in Lync client and it isn't able to be deleted or renamed.

So the answer is **no**. This cannot be removed.

Comment: I poked around *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync* as per info found at http://http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933096.aspx, but no joy.  I think you're right, it can't be removed.

Comment: I don't understand why they add groups no one wants and doesn't let you rename them...